# Ruby on Rails - Getting "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column" for one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, one-to-many

I have two models, model_1 and model_2.

model_1.rb:

```
has_many :model_2s
```

model_2.rb:

```
belongs_to :model_1
```

But when i try to do `@model_1.model_2s` I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'model_2.model_1_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `model_2`.* FROM `sketches` WHERE (`model_2s`.model_1_id = 1))
```

I have the same problem using SQLite3. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you added an index to your migration for your foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the has_many by default relies on conventions.

`has_many :model_2s`

would use the column "model_1_id" in the "model_2" table by default to find what "model_1" it belongs to (hey, you chose the name of the models ;)). But you seem to be missing that column.

For reasons unknown (unless you provide your migration files) your table is missing that column.

Comment: Oops... I didn't put it in my migration file!